# High Availability and Load Balancing in RabbitMq

Tags: rabbitmq

Consider a cluster with A and B nodes,I want a solution which meet these requirements:

1) When node A goes down the system continue working properly with node B till node A comes up again

2) Preventing extra network hop when master node is on Node A and client was connected to Node B, so when client publish a message, RAbbitmq route it to Node A i want to pervent this extra network hop

I should write my balancer or any framework (like HA Proxy) exist that can do these requirements?

Comment: I think question 1 is fairly straightforward, but it's not clear at all by what you mean in question 2. Could you please clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Your question was recently discussed on the `rabbitmq-users` mailing list: [link](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/rabbitmq-users/Clp0CG2CnOI/discussion).

I recommend reading it.

For question #2, don't worry about the extra hop unless you have proof it causes an issue for you.

Comment: I feel this answer could use a bit more meat. Have you considered pulling the relevant points from the discussion?

Comment: Writing something once is enough. That's what links are for. If someone else wants to copypasta, they can have at it.

Comment: Links go dead, and this answer may outlast the link, which is why the answer guidelines strongly discourage link-only answers. As-is, this is a comment, not an answer. Sorry :/

Comment: @LukeBakken theMayer is right that in general, we want our content to survive link rot. This is not about copy-pasta, but about providing the relevant information in the answer itself (which may or may not involve direct quotes).

Comment: That said, this is _at least_ a partial answer, answering #2, so more than a comment.

Comment: @LukeBakken thanks for answer. So i understand  from ur answer that Extra hop is impalpable and it will not a performance issue in future?